# How to determine the limit of this function

Tags: calculus, limits

I am struggling with the following function

$$f(x) = \left|\sin\left(\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-x\right)\right|$$

I am interested in the limit towards infinity, and I know that this limit should be:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\propto \frac{1}{x}$$

I figured that in the limit the absolute value signs may not be that important, and naively tried to transform $z=1/x$ and do something that I am familiar with (first order Taylor expansion, since I knew the outcome), but it is only giving me a headache for now. Any advise on how this limit should be tackled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply and divide by $$\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+x$$ inside the sine function. This is a rationalization technique that works in many situations.

Comment: Wow, this makes it looks such an easy problem all at once. Thanks!